# Rails 3: Select all submodels where submodel has a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

My Rails db scheme has projects and task. I want to show projects which have at least one open task. This is my code:

```
class Project
    scope :open_tasks, lambda {
        where(:tasks => {:finished => false}).includes(:tasks)
    }
    ...
end
```

This code correctly returns the projects with one open task, but only with the one open tasks and not all. e.g. a project has 5 tasks total and 2 open task, the code from above would return only the project with 2 tasks. I know that I could simply force to reload the project, but this is very hackish and has performance problems.
How can I get the project with all tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` condition is always going to limit which associated tasks are returned.

It sounds like you want to return the projects and **all of their associated tasks regardless of status** if at least one of those tasks is not finished?

You could try this (I don't think you need the lambda since you're not using any variables/times/etc. in your scope). It assumes you have a `has_many :tasks` and `belongs_to :project`. You'd need to tweak it if you're using a has_many :through, etc.

```
scope :open_tasks, where("(select count(*) from tasks where tasks.project_id=projects.id) > 0").includes(:tasks)
```

Comment: Hi,the lambda is from previous tests. Your solution works, thanks.